# Translate require to ES6 (adal)

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I've installed `adal-angular` following [this](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-office-365-web-applications-react/) project, and it has:

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('expose?AuthenticationContext!adal-angular');
```

How can I translate it to `import context from package` syntax?

Comment: import AuthenticationContext from 'expose?AuthenticationContext!adal-angular', not working?

Comment: No, it did not work. It says: `cannot find module expose`

Comment: Then I realized... I added `expose-loader` but now webpack says me: `Unexpected '!' in 'expose?AuthenticationContext!adal-angular'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax`